# 2D top-down minimap

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'd like to make a minimap of my rpg game.

Is making a minimap as simple as dividing all object dimensions, velocities, and coordinates by however large you want the minimap?

For example below... You have a size of 1000x1000px, a canvas (viewport) of 500x500px, the player is located in the center of the viewport... If you wanted a minimap half the size of the actual world, you would do:

- Player/Viewport `x,y` velocity/2
- Player/Viewport `x,y` coordinates/2
- Canvas, world, and all objects' width and height are divided by 2

etc...

[image]

That way the rendering of the minimap on the world and the velocities are scaled accurately? Am I missing anything?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**: Something like this?

```
function miniMap() {
  $(".minimapHolder").show();
  $("#mini_map").text("hide minimap");
  var minicanvas = document.getElementById("miniMap");  
  ministage = new createjs.Stage("miniMap");
  minicam = new createjs.Shape();
  minicam.graphics.beginStroke("white").drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 40, 5);
  //blip representation of Player
  player_blip = new createjs.Shape();   
  player_blip.graphics.beginFill("yellow").drawRoundRect(0, 0, 11.2, 12, 1);

  animal_blip = new createjs.Shape();   
  animal_blip.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRoundRect(0, 0, 24.4, 21.6, 1);

  player_blip.x = players_Array[0].x/5;
  player_blip.y = players_Array[0].y/5;

  animal_blip.x = animalContainer.x/5;
  animal_blip.y = animalContainer.y/5;

  minicam.x = players_Array[0].x-110;   
  minicam.y = players_Array[0].y-110;   
  ministage.addChild(player_blip, animal_blip, minicam);
  ministage.update();

}

function updateMiniMap() {
  player_blip.x = players_Array[0].x/5;
  player_blip.y = players_Array[0].y/5;

  if (ContainerOfAnimals.children[0] != null) {
      var pt = ContainerOfAnimals.localToGlobal(ContainerOfAnimals.children[0].x, ContainerOfAnimals.children[0].y);
      console.log(pt.x);

      animal_blip.x = pt.x/5;
      animal_blip.y = pt.y/5;
  } else {
      ministage.removeChild(animal_blip);
  }
  minicam.x = player_blip.x-40;     
  minicam.y = player_blip.y-15;                     
  ministage.update();
  }
```

Gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short anwswer: "It will(most likely) work." ... **but:**

What you are trying to achieve is just *scaling the stage/container*, so you could also just use a copy of everything and put it into a container and scale it down to 0.5, but that is **not** the purpose of a minimap.

Objects of the minimap should only be a **representation** of the object in the 'real' world and should therefore not have any velocity ect.(that should especially not be updated separately from the 'real' world) - while your approach will probably work, you'd allways have to keep track and update every property, this will get messy quickly or even lead to differences if you miss some tiny things.

**A more 'clean'(and simple) approach** to this would be, that each minimap-object has a reference to the object in the 'real' world and on each tick, it just reads the x/y-coordinates and updates its' own coordinates based on the minimap-scale.

Another thing is the graphics: Scaling-operations can be costly(performance wise), especially when they are done each frame, so IF you use the same graphics for the minimap you should at least used a cached DisplayObject and not have the graphics scaled each frame.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a clean approach! - I'm guessing that having only 1 `animal_blib` is by design, right?

Comment: Well I'll eventually have x amount of blips, so I'll modify the code to create a new createJS object each time a new object is added.